# Visual Basic VB.Net - GUI Pause Checkbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm attempting to create a checkbox that will pause the current function when clicked. Here's how my code is set up-

```
Public Function Wait()
    LogOutput("Application paused.")
    Do Until waitBox.Checked = False
        'Task.Delay(1000)
        My.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    LogOutput("Application unpaused.")
Return Nothing
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function Thing()
   For Each i In x
      If waitBox.Checked Then
          Wait()
      Else
          DoStuff()
      End If
   Loop
Return Nothing
End Function
```

As you can see I've tried "Task.Delay" as well as "DoEvents(), however the problem is that the GUI is locked up while the function is running and so the user is unable to click pause at all.

How can I get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new thread for that, so the GUI is not locked:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think a `BackgroundWorker` would be sufficient for this (same idea). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I think the BackgroundWorker class is a bit too advanced for me at this stage. I'm not sure at all how to implement it into my code. I'll try to convert my function into a class and follow Shadow's example and see if I can get anywhere. Thanks guys.